# How to calculate the mean value of the rows of a matrix, ignoring any values equal to 0

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

```
list = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 0, 4}, {4,5,6}};
```

How do I calculate the mean of the rows but ignoring the entries that have a `0`? The answers should be `1.5, 3.5, 5.0`.

Comment: It's simple, I think: `Map[Mean[#]&, DeleteCases[list,0]]`

Comment: @RiccardoCazzin You didn't remove the zeros.  Also, you can replace `Mean[#]&` with simply `Mean`.

Comment: Try something like `N@*Mean@*DeleteCases[0] /@ list`.

Comment: `Mean /@ DeleteCases[list, 0, Infinity]`

Comment: @jjc385 you're right: it's `Map[Mean, DeleteCases[list, 0, 2]]`

Comment: @jjc385 it's done now. Thanks :D

Comment: Yes, thank you everyone. Sure wish Mathematica would make this more intuitive, or at least give an example on their "Mean" page. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First delete the zeros with `DeleteCases` (on all levels), the `Map` (`/@`) the `Mean` on all rows:

```
Mean /@ DeleteCases[list, 0, Infinity]
```

> {3/2, 7/2, 5}

You can add `N` if you want decimal output:

```
N@%
```

> {1.5, 3.5, 5.}

Comment: Why `Infinity` rather than `{2}`?  Presumably the latter is more efficient.  +1

Comment: @jjc385 Because it's more general. If you want to make it a function and then use on something with more levels, you'll need to adjust. If you have a specific issue just go with `{2}`, but I'd go with `Infinity` to not worry in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `0`'s with `Nothing` to remove them from the list

```
Mean /@ (list /. 0 -> Nothing)
```

Comment: @TomMozdzen add a space between `/.` and `0`

Comment: My bad - had a white space issue - yes works great too!

Answer (score 4):

If your lists are large, this s/b faster (if speed matters):

```
Total[#]/Total[Unitize@#] &@Transpose@list
```